# Google Maps Node.JS Travel Time in Minutes

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get the travel time between two locations in minutes, instead of in the format hours and minutes. The code I am using is:

```
    var distance = require('google-distance');

    distance.get({
        origin: 'San Francisco, CA',
        destination: 'San Diego, CA'
    },function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(data.duration.value);
        }
    });
```

I read somewhere that duration.value gets the time in seconds, which I can easily convert to minutes. However this yields undefined. When I leave as data.duration I get the time in # hours # mins. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [`data.durationValue`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-distance#user-content-usage), not `data.duration.value` that gives the duration in seconds.

Once you have it just divide by 60 to get minutes.

Comment: Thank you that worked! Just out of curiosity, is there anywhere I can find the API for this?

Comment: I couldn't find any, although the package home page linked to in my answer seems to have decent amount of info. It doesn't seem that complex - just a very thin wrapper over google's API. So you could just refer google's [doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/) and then refer the module's [source](https://github.com/edwlook/node-google-distance/blob/master/index.js) to see how they map the API response to fields.